# Processing large number of rasters using ArcPy but it only saves last file

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I am using a Python script for running an iteration of raster calculator. The operation is a conditional clause for changing no-data values to "0". The script is the following

```py
import arcpy 
from arcpy.sa import *
 
arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\GIS\SourceData\Model\EnergyWet'
for r in arcpy.ListRasters("*"): # list all rasters in workspace
    outRaster = Con(IsNull(Raster(r)),0,Raster(r)) #perfoms Conditional
    outRaster.save(r['F:\GIS\SourceData\Model\EnergyWet\zeroed\-4'] + "out.tif") #save output
```

It appears to work, depending on the route in the last line, But it only saves the last iteration.

What is wrong with my script?

Answer (score 1):

Where you have an output file name of:

```
r['F:\GIS\SourceData\Model\EnergyWet\zeroed\-4'] + "out.tif"
```

you have a random variable called `r` next to a list, so that's bad syntax and apparently you are concatenating a string to a list which makes no sense.

Ignoring all the syntax issues nothing about the output name changes so the logic of your script is to constantly overwrite its output.

A better script would be:

```
import arcpy 
from arcpy.sa import *
 
arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\GIS\SourceData\Model\EnergyWet'
for r in arcpy.ListRasters("*"): # list all rasters in workspace
    outRaster = Con(IsNull(Raster(r)),0,Raster(r)) #perfoms Conditional
    outRaster.save(r"F:\GIS\SourceData\Model\EnergyWet\zeroed\" + r + ".tif")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
The syntax seems to work now, but I still have the same issue, The script seems to run all the operations but it only returns the last one as output.
How can I make the script save every single output in the iteration?
I appreciate ny mre guidance since I'm new to python scripting

Comment: Edit your question show whats in the folder EnergyWet. Put a print statement within the loop to see what `r` is.